# Query on Stellar based cross border payment

Tags: xlm, token, stellar-laboratory, trustline, nodes

I have a query regarding cross border payments based on stellar Actually we are building a solution of cross border payment based on stellar, as I have read the documentation , I have found that there is an Horizon API through which one should have to connect in order to achieve cross border payment/transaction(native/issued token), but I didn't find any fiat on/off ramp API  provided by stellar  through which we can get an issued token in the user's wallet with respect to the fiat that user have deposited to the stellar network and also need the API of getting the list of anchors that stellar have in their network . Suggestion would be appreciated. *